# Help Magento 2 coupon code checkout

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.5

I need to make it mandatory (required field) to enter a coupon code during checkout. Do you have any suggestions?

Alternatively, prevent the checkout order confirmation if a coupon code is not entered.

I'm using magento 2.4.5.

thanks